# Landscape resource not picked up via LayoutInflater

Tags: android

I am trying to dynamically add buttons to table rows, but need to alter the style of the buttons based on screen orientation.  I have the following "game_answer_button.xml" layout file in both "layout" and "layout-land" folders.

**res/layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
```

**res/layout-land:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
    />
```

The button layout is being inflated in my activity as follows:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
Button button = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_answer_button, null);
button.setText(image.getDescription());
```

However, it seems the default (portrait) layout is selected every time.  If the contents of the default layout are replaced with the landscape layout, then the landscape layout is finally rendered.  It doesn't seem to be correctly selecting the landscape layout resource via LayoutInflater.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I was loading the dynamic buttons to an ArrayList and merely adding the buttons to my parent view on each configuration change--meaning the button style would have already been inflated when pulling the button objects from "cache".  Just another Dev "doh!" moment.

Answer (score 0):

did you check if the configuration of the activity, where the button is used, in the manifest is set to portrait only?

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed in the manifest that the activity has no particular orientation attribute set.